# Counting # elements in multiple arrays using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, count

I'm trying to count how many existing elements there are in all `columns` within `taskIds`. Not sure what the most efficient way to do this as I am already mapping data in the return statement. I want to be able to pass the total number in `CustomHeader`. Expected value should return 5

I have this component:

```
const Example = () => {

  const [state] = useContext(DataContext);
  const count = 0;
  return (
    <>
      <div
        title={<CustomHeader title="Things to do" size="18px" count={count} />}
      >
        {state.columnOrder.map(columnId => {
          const column = state.columns[columnId];
          const tasks = column.taskIds.map(taskId => state.tasks[taskId]);
          return <Item key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

and this is my DataContext:

```
tasks: {
        "task-1": { id: "task-1", description: "Test" },
        ...
      },
      columns: {
        "column-1": {
          id: "column-1",
          taskIds: ["task-1", "task-2", "task-3", "task-4"]
        },
        "column-2": {
          id: "column-2",
          title: "column-2",
          taskIds: ["task-5"]
        },
        "column-3": {
          id: "column-3",
          title: "column-3",
          taskIds: []
        }
      },

      columnOrder: ["column-1", "column-2", "column-3"]

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) on your `.columns` object within your state. This will give you an array of objects which are the values from within your `columns` object. Using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can then sum the length of each `taskIds` array by taking the `.length` and adding that to the accumulating sum `acc`:

```js
const state = { tasks: { "task-1": { id: "task-1", description: "Test" }, }, columns: { "column-1": { id: "column-1", taskIds: ["task-1", "task-2", "task-3", "task-4"] }, "column-2": { id: "column-2", title: "column-2", taskIds: ["task-5"] }, "column-3": { id: "column-3", title: "column-3", taskIds: [] } }, columnOrder: ["column-1", "column-2", "column-3"] };

const getCount = state =>
  Object.values(state.columns).reduce((acc, {taskIds}) => acc+taskIds.length, 0);
  
console.log(getCount(state));
```

Answer (score 0):

create a temp array and place the values of all inside it, then do .length on the temp array if possible I would change the naming convention from column-3 to column3 as well but whatever works

Comment: Any reason for the naming convention suggestion? :)

Comment: @Freddy. not the original answerer, but "-" is not allowed in identifiers. Sure you can access _column-3_ using bracket notation (ie: `obj.tasks.columns["column-3"]` works fine), but, when using it in dot-notation: `obj.tasks.colums.column-3`, you're going to get an unexpected result, as `-` is interpreted as subtraction.

Comment: What @NickParsons said

Comment: @NickParsons I see thanks nick. How do I dynamically access all columns object and count all object property taskIds? var test = state.columns["column-3"].taskIds; only accesses 1 object trying to get a total of all columns

Answer (score 0):

Since both (columns and tasks) are object you can count them directly by this function:

```
  Object.keys(columns).length
  Object.keys(tasks).length

  <CustomHeader title="Things to do" size="18px" count={Object.keys(columns).length} />
```

Comment: Not sure I quite follow. I could create a function within the map to count the tasks? Are you able to expand your answer using the code I have?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new uplaod  your cdoe here and sure :)   (i don't know your 
 code for sure, jsut upload the important parts and do comments  // here i need the count of columns ...)